# can app backdate post to a wall?

Tags: facebook, feed

can app backdate post to a wall? I want to back date because app profile pages are going away and I thought maybe I can re-post to new page with old date from app profile page.

Answer (score 0):

A Facebook rep [told Mashable](http://mashable.com/2011/09/27/facebook-timeline-pages/): “We hope to make Pages more consistent with the new Timeline in the future.” So you probably will be able to create open graph actions which lie in the past.